Hypothesis: test defensive programming
I'm writing tests with Hypothesis to test functions with restricted range. Consider the following toy example:
import math
from hypothesis import assume, example, given

def inc(value: float) -> float:
    assert not math.isnan(value)
    return value + 1

@given(st.floats())
def test_inc(value: float):
    assume(not math.isnan(value))
    if(value == math.inf or value == -math.inf):
        assert inc(value) == value
    else:
        assert inc(value) > value

Here I'm testing the behaviour for finite and infinite inputs, but not NaN. I would like to test that out-of-range values, such as NaN, correctly throw an AssertionError.
Is there a pattern built into Hypothesis where I can test this? Ideally I'd like an approach where I don't compromise the coverage of within-range values.

Hypothesis
is an amazing package, which likely will teach you
new things about your code that you hadn't anticipated.
So many failure modes!

You asked an XY
question that you already know the answer to.

I would like to test that out-of-range values, such as NaN, correctly throw an AssertionError.

Clearly you want to elide the assume, so that
assert not math.isnan() will trigger.
Please feel free to post a stackoverflow question which asks the real thing you're concerned about.
The details matter.
Show us the details.

If I remove the call to assume and replace it with a check that the function threw an exception, then I'm not guaranteed to have ample coverage for both within- and out-of-domain values. This is a question about ensuring coverage for multiple cases within a single test function.
